# Creating SQL database table from large XML data

Tags: sql, xml, database, parsing

I have a huge XML data (more than 1GB) that I need to import on a new SQL table. 
Is there a free tool / software / way that I can use to create a table automatically from that XML file? 
I searched on some posts here on stackoverflow, but all of the provided solutions and recommendations requires knowledge on the XML entities information, which I do not have as it was not possible to parse the file correctly.
Thank you in advance

Comment: How can you not parse it correctly? Is it invalid XML?

Comment: Also, parsing XML data into a relational structure depends on what RDBMS you're using. All the major RDBMSs have some support for XML, but they're not all the same.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

You can use the free **R** (install [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) and [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) in that order) for that. It has a library called `XML` that handles large amounts of XML data pretty well if you have a good machine (all data is loaded into RAM).

Inside RStudio you can use the commands

```
require(XML)
filename <- [filepath relative to working directory]
data <- xmlParse(filename)
```

to create your data frame called `data`, i.e. load the XML data into a tabular format, which you can then save in a different format or process further inside R. In contrast to SQL databases is also quite lenient with data types (if that should be the source of your issues).